# NHibernate group by and order by division of two conditional sum

Tags: nhibernate, queryover

I have the following code:

```
var classAttendanceDetails =
                        Session.QueryOver<StudentClassAttendanceDetails>(() => scadAlias)
                            .JoinAlias(() => scadAlias.StudentClassAttendence, () => scaAlias)
                            .JoinAlias(() => scaAlias.Lecture, () => lAlias).JoinAlias(() => scaAlias.Teacher, () => tAlias).JoinAlias(() => scadAlias.StudentProgram, () => spAlias);
    var queryover = classAttendanceDetails
                        .Select(
                            Projections.Group<StudentClassAttendanceDetails>(c => scaAlias.Lecture),
                            Projections.Group<StudentClassAttendanceDetails>(c => scaAlias.Teacher),
                            Projections.Sum(
                                Projections.Conditional(
                                    Restrictions.Where<StudentClassAttendanceDetails>(f => f.StudentFeedback == 1),
                                    Projections.Constant(1),
                                    Projections.Constant(0))),
                            Projections.Sum(
                                Projections.Conditional(
                                    Restrictions.Where<StudentClassAttendanceDetails>(f => f.StudentFeedback == 2),
                                    Projections.Constant(1),
                                    Projections.Constant(0))),
                            Projections.Sum(
                                Projections.Conditional(
                                    Restrictions.Where<StudentClassAttendanceDetails>(f => f.StudentFeedback == 3),
                                    Projections.Constant(1),
                                    Projections.Constant(0))),
                            Projections.Sum(
                                Projections.Conditional(
                                    Restrictions.Where<StudentClassAttendanceDetails>(
                                        f => f.StudentFeedback.IsIn(new[] {1, 2, 3})),
                                    Projections.Constant(1),
                                    Projections.Constant(0))),
                                    Projections.SqlFunction(
                    new VarArgsSQLFunction("(", "/", ")"),
                    NHibernateUtil.Int32,
                    Projections.Sum(
                Projections.Conditional(
                    Restrictions.Where<StudentClassAttendanceDetails>(f => f.StudentFeedback == 1),
                    Projections.Constant(1),
                    Projections.Constant(0))),
                    Projections.Conditional(
                    Restrictions.Where<StudentClassAttendanceDetails>(f => f.StudentFeedback.IsIn(new[] { 1, 2, 3 })),
                    Projections.Constant(1),
                    Projections.Constant(0)))
                                    ).OrderBy(Projections.SqlFunction(
            new VarArgsSQLFunction("(", "/", ")"),
            NHibernateUtil.Int32,
            Projections.Sum(
        Projections.Conditional(
            Restrictions.Where<StudentClassAttendanceDetails>(f => f.StudentFeedback == 1),
            Projections.Constant(1),
            Projections.Constant(0))),
            Projections.Conditional(
            Restrictions.Where<StudentClassAttendanceDetails>(f => f.StudentFeedback.IsIn(new[] { 1, 2, 3 })),
            Projections.Constant(1),
            Projections.Constant(0)))).Desc;
```

Here I am trying to order the result by  number of results where feedback is 1  devided by no of results where feedback is 1/2/3.But i can not order by this because it is not included in the group by.How can i include it in group by